# how initiate a validation form using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do the following validation on my registration page;

at the beginning of the page I have,

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['sumbit']) && (!validateName($_POST['phonenumber'])) {
here html show errors if the form was submitted with errors
<form method= "post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<div>Phone Number</div>
<input type="text" name="phonenumber" size="20" placeholder="phone" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['phonenumber']); ?>" required>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

but I am getting "Notice: Undefined index: phonenumber in ...." before submit page

I have the validationName function in a separated file that I call from here but I am getting error

any help??

Comment: The error indicates that $_POST['phonenumber'] does not exist. Try 'print_r($_POST)' and see what you get.

Comment: @danielson317: `Array` he should get ;-)

Comment: Only call your validateThing when it got submitted. For instance when `$_POST["submit"]` is set. (It shouldn't be `sumbit` btw.)

Comment: @RichardReiber oops. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting new var like `$phn_number = isset($_POST['phonenumber']);`

```
 if(!isset($_POST['sumbit']) && (!validateName($phn_number)) {
```

Its just a NOTICE, you may work even if continues.

Answer (score 3):

You have to validate that the variable is set:

```
if(isset($_POST['var']))
```

or (for checking if it is not empty):

```
if(!empty($_POST['var']))
```

But you can just ignore notices, this is not the best solution, but they are not shown on productive environments. Furthermore, you can leave out this:

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"
```

For your error (variable not set), try this for displaying all POSTed things:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

EDIT: There is another logical mistake:

```
if(!isset($_POST['sumbit']) && (!validateName($_POST['phonenumber'])) {
```

Should be this, to display something in case of error:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !validateName($_POST['phonenumber'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && (!validateName($_POST['phonenumber'])) {
```

notice the lack of '!' and you hava a typo 'sumbit'. But to make it simpler it could be

```
if(isset($_POST['phonenumber']) && (!validateName($_POST['phonenumber'])) {
```